# Is this mapping an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Define $\phi:\mathbb Q[\sqrt3]\rightarrow \mathbb Q[\sqrt7]$ by $\phi(a+b\sqrt3)=(a+b\sqrt7)$.

Is $\phi$ isomorphic? Is there any isomorphism at all?

So I started this by writing for the given a,b and another pair $(c+d\sqrt3)$ checking the additive and multiplicative properties to see if this is a homomorphism, and I know in order for it to be isomorphic, the kernal must be $\langle 0 \rangle$, which I believe should be true because in order for this to be $0$, both a and be must equal $0$.

I dont think this is isomorphic by the wording of the question, but cant tell if there is any isomorphism at all?

Comment: Hint: a homomorphism sends $1$ to $1$. Now consider the preimage of $\sqrt{7}$. What properties will this have?

Comment: You should have had trouble verifying the multiplicative property (why?)...

Comment: Yes I did, which is why I said this was not an iso--I think im mainly stuff as to how to tell if there is any isom at all?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*. $\sqrt3$ is an element of the domain whose square is equal to $3$. What is the square of its image under your map?